# How to get correct automatic continuation lines in F90 mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fortran, fortran90

Assume I am writing some (free-format) Fortran Code in F90 mode, how do I get correct automatic continuation lines when typing and how do I get correctly continued lines when using `fill-paragraph`?

A code example:

```
subroutine procedure_with_many_arguments(argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5, argument6, argument7)

real ::  argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5, argument6, argument7

end subroutine
```

**1. When typing this code with `auto-fill-mode`**, I get the continuation character `&`on *both* lines and also some strange fixed-format-like indentation (ommiting the second and third statements here):

```
subroutine procedure_with_many_arguments(argument1, argument2, argument3,&
     & argument4, argument5, argument6, argument7)
```

**2. When using `fill-paragraph` on already existing, too wide code**, I get *neither* any continuation character `&`, *nor* any indentation:

```
subroutine procedure_with_many_arguments(argument1, argument2, argument3,
argument4, argument5, argument6, argument7)

real :: argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5, argument6,
argument7

end subroutine
```

**Expected result:**

```
subroutine procedure_with_many_arguments(argument1, argument2, &
  argument4, argument5, argument6, argument7)

real :: argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4, argument5, &
  argument6, argument7)

end subroutine
```

Comment: *What if Stack Overflow existed 25 years ago*

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know how to process that comment...

Comment: Having the continuation marker on both lines isn't _wrong_, simply not to many tastes.

Comment: @Michael I don't know what you mean but the question is about a source form *introduced* 25 years ago. It is still valid even in current Fortran 2015.

Comment: I can confirm this.. the extra ampersand would maybe appear to be attempting to make hybrid fixed-free compatible code, but its not correct at that either since then the first one would need to be pushed out past col 72.

Comment: What are you talking about @Michael?

Comment: I managed to get rid of the leading ampersand (see edit) by spotting the appropriate option in the major modes code (`f90.el`). However, i'm totally lost on the `fill-paragraph` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my on question here:

**1. To get rid of the leading ampersand**, add the following lines to your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq f90-mode-hook
  '(lambda () (setq f90-beginning-ampersand nil)))
```

**2. To break too wide lines of already existing code**, use `f90-fill-region` instead of `fill-paragraph`.

Note that the`f90-fill-region` command crashes Emacs when used on comment lines (versions 24.5.1 and 25.3.1 tested) and the `fill-paragraph`command does nothing on them. There seems to be no fill-command suitable for both code, and comment lines.

**Update:** The maintainer of the free form Fortran major mode`f90.el` just pushed an [update](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/b9d7c902603a49d2624bdd35efdfba1785a4bce5) to GitHub that adds a function `f90-fill-paragraph`. This command works both on comment lines and code.